# Evaluate Ricci tensor at specific coordinate

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, curvature

Let's use 2D space and 1D time. There is a point mass at origo $(0, 0, 0)$ with mass $M$ just to keep things simple. What are the Ricci tensor elements at $(x, y, 0)$? I've found lot's of ways to symbolically calculate the tensor elements in various scenarios, but what if I want a specific values for e.g. visualising on a grid or similar. In 2+0D space, it seems only the Ricci scalar is needed if I understand things correctly.

Comment: You might find 2D space is not what you really want because the dimension changes the gravity.

Comment: The Ricci tensor is zero in vacuum, no matter the dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming in this answer that we are considering standard General Relativity, albeit in $2+1$ dimensional spacetime. By that I mean we assume Einstein's Equations,
$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} = 8 \pi T_{\mu\nu}$$
to hold.

If that is indeed the case, then let us pick an arbitrary point $(x,y,0)$ away from the origin. In this point, the RHS vanishes, since you asked for an isolated mass at the origin. Hence, we get
$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} = 0.$$
If we multiply by $g^{\mu\nu}$ and contract, we'll find that
$$\begin{align}
g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}R g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} &= 0, \\
R - \frac{3}{2}R &= 0, \\
R &= 0,
\end{align}$$
and replacing this result in the original equation we find $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$.

For a $(2+1)$D spacetime, the Ricci tensor (not scalar) contains all the information available in the Riemann tensor. Hence, $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ means the metric is flat in every point that is not the origin. I'm not certain, but I'm quite sure that if you want the metric to be continuous (if it isn't the Riemann tensor won't be well-defined), it will have to be flat at the origin as well. Notice that $(2+1)$D doesn't allow a Newtonian approximation.

As for 2 dimensional, the same calculation I wrote above will lead to
$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}R g_{\mu\nu} = 0.$$
The reason being, as you stated, that the Ricci scalar completely determines the curvature. As a consequence, Einstein equations will become
$T_{\mu\nu} = 0,$$
and the only solutions are trivial.

For more on this, you might want to take a look at Sec. 15.2 of Thanu Padmanabhan's [Gravitation: Foundations and Frontiers](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/gravitation/AE442EE4214091F5DB46499ECAD69E32).

Comment: I' wondering why you write $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ means that the spacetime is flat in every point that is not the origin? I just had a look at the derivation of the outer Schwarzschild metric (in Fließbach, general relativity, german version) and there is $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ taken to derive A=1/B and the final metric, which is surely not flat. They state, instead, that $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ means that there are **no sources** of curvature.

Comment: @BarrierRemoval I haven't checked that particular book, but notice that most textbooks will derive the Schwarzschild solution in $3+1$ gravity, in which case $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ indeed only means no sources are present in that point. That is because $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ does not imply $R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = 0$ on four dimensional manifolds. However, OP asked for $2+1$ dimensional gravity, and in three dimensional manifolds $R_{\mu\nu}$ implies $R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = 0$, which means the metric is flat

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I was not aware of this difference between 2+1 and 3+1 dimensional gravity.

Comment: So in essence it's always zero for 2D space? What about the Ricci scalar? Is it also always 0?

Comment: @vidstige If you assume the Einstein Equations, the curvature will vanish in $(2+1)$D spacetime wherever there is no matter (I'm considering the cosmological constant to be "matter" in this sentence: for $\Lambda \neq 0$, there is curvature). As a consequence, the Ricci scalar will vanish wherever there is no matter as well. As for $2$D spacetime, the Einstein equations demand the absence of matter, so things are quite dull. The Ricci scalar might not be zero, but there can be no matter

Comment: Wait, hold up, this doesn't make sense. So with this reasoning there is only curvature where there is mass. For example around the sun, there would be no curvature - Only inside the sun where there is mass? Certainly mass must affect curvature in a surrounding somehow?

Comment: @vidstige in $2+1$ dimensions, there is only curvature where there is mass. In $3+1$ dimensions things are quite different, as we know. The number of dimensions is extremely relevant

Comment: I see. But wherein lies the difference? You only used the general (dimension-agnostic) form in your argumentation in this answer from what I can tell?

Comment: @vidstige there is a small difference: in $2+1$ dimensions, all the curvature is given by the Ricci tensor. In $3+1$, the Riemann tensor has more components and the Ricci tensor does not suffice to describe the curvature completely. In both cases the Ricci tensor vanishes, but in $3+1$ you have other curvature components. These form the so-called Weyl tensor. Together, the Weyl tensor and the Ricci tensor have all of the information present on the Riemann tensor

Comment: @vidstige there's also another point I forgot to mention (but it is irrelevant for the difference between $2+1$ and $3+1$): the trace of the metric is dimension-dependent. Namely, $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = d$, where $d$ is the spacetime dimension

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot!